# How to write all the data in session to string[] also how to write the data in string [] to session

Tags: asp.net, session-variables

I using a `ASP.net`. I need to copy all the session data (both session variables and session request variables) to `String []`. How can i do this?

Also i need the reverse condition.

How can i do this using Serialization concepts

Answer (score 2):

Serialization and Deserialization should do the trick.

You can look [here](http://aspalliance.com/983_Introducing_Serialization_in_NET) for a tutorial on serialization.